# Eager-Loading External Data Associated with an Active Record Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to combine data from an `ActiveRecord` model with external data related to each object and I'm trying to figure out a clean and performant way to accomplish this.

I can obviously define an instance method on the model to fetch the corresponding external data:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  def counties
    @counties ||= fetch_external_data(state: name)['counties']
  end
end

State.find_by_name('Alabama').counties
```

But if I have a collection of objects (via an `ActiveRecord::Relation`), then this would result in an N+1 query to this external data source.

```
State.where(name: %w[Alabama Georgia]).map(&:counties)
```

Ideally, I would eager-load all of the data from the external data source and then have the `counties` instance method access data from this "shared" object. I could do this using a class method:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :counties

  def self.with_counties
    # Get external data for all states in our scope
    counties = fetch_external_data(states: pluck(:name))

    # Group by the state
    counties_by_state = counties.group_by { |c| c['state'] }

    # Now hydrate all of the state models and set the counties
    all.map do |state|
      state.counties = counties_by_state.dig(state.name, 'counties')
    end
  end
end
```

While this is possible, it prevents me from being able to further chain scopes after using `State.where(name: %w[Alabama Georgia]).with_counties` and it just feels like it could be handled more elegantly.

Is there a clear way to "eager-load" data like this (i.e. being able to set "collection data" on the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object that can be accessed when the record is hydrated)? If I have a class that represents this external data interface, are there methods that I could define on this class to make it work with `State.includes(:counties)` or `State.eager_load(:counties)`?

Any thoughts or suggestions would  be appreciated.

Comment: While I understand the intention behind this, I would advise against such approach, chaining scopes should really have no side effects and making external calls is a nasty one. In this case, I would probably write a decorator to wrap the relation and use it very explicitly.

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej Decorators were the other approach that I had toyed with for this. I could only really find examples where they were used specifically for views and this data will likely be consumed elsewhere in the app so I wasn't sure if that was a good pattern or not. I think your point about it being more explicit makes a lot of sense, though.